# How do I make a contact form without using a table?

Tags: css, forms, html, tags

I want to make a contact form for my website.  i want to make it without using a table.  How do I do that?  I was looking at div tags because I want to style it with CSS.  I want to give it a length and width.  I want to place it in a main div tag but I am not sure how I do so.  Please help me.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try searching on Google: "contact form CSS".

You will get so many examples with the code provided that you will get lost :D

Have a look on these two.

**[css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/nice-and-simple-contact-form/)**

**[net.tutsplus.com](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/build-a-neat-html5-powered-contact-form/)**

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I've used something similar to this-

```
<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="/contact-us" method="post">
    <div class="form-col">
        <input type="text" name="Requester.FirstName" class="styled" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="text" name="Requester.LastName" class="styled" placeholder="Last Name">
        <div class="selector fixedWidth">
           <span>Subject</span>
           <select name="Subject" class="styled">
            <option value="">Subject</option>
            <option value="custserv">Customer Service</option>
            <option value="vendor">Vendor</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <textarea name="message" class="styled"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-col">
        <input type="text" name="Requester.ContactInfo.Email" class="styled" placeholder="Email Address">
        <input type="text" name="Requester.ContactInfo.Phone" class="styled" placeholder="Phone Number">

        <span class="question">How do you prefer to be contacted?</span>
        <label for="contact-method-phone">
            <div class="radio" id="uniform-contact-method-phone"><span><input type="radio" name="ContactMethod" id="contact-method-phone" value="HomePhone" class="styled"></span></div>Phone
        </label>
        <label for="contact-method-email">
            <div class="radio" id="uniform-contact-method-phone"><span><input type="radio" name="ContactMethod" id="contact-method-phone" value="Email" class="styled"></span></div>Email
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="Address.StreetAddress1" class="styled" placeholder="Address">
        <input type="text" name="Address.StreetAddress1" class="styled">
        <input type="submit" value="CONTACT US" class="m-form-button" name="CONTACT US">
    </div>
</form>
```

And I try to follow [SMACSS](http://smacss.com/) when styling